# OpenCV Logs and Android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am running OpenCV on Android, and in my IDE, Android Studio I get this lines on each frame:

```
06-11 16:58:04.891 18591-18591/com.package D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 3110400
06-11 16:58:04.908 18591-18663/com.package D/CameraBridge: mStretch value: 1.0
06-11 16:58:04.922 18591-18663/com.package D/FpsMeter: 6.54 FPS@1920x1080
```

Now these show up in Verbose and Debug mode, and the last line shows up in Info level as well.

My question is this, are these lines also written locally on my device ? I am just worried that it might cause performance issues if I keep printing them.. or might already be causing problems ?

I found this: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6064 but I don't understand how to apply the fix.. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

That solution states that you should create a new log class in the `org.opencv.engine.manager` package

```
class Log {
    public static int v(String tag, String msg) {
         if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
             android.util.Log.v(tag, msg); //make sure to call android.util here because otherwise you will have a recursion
         }
    }
    public static int w(String tag, String msg) {
         if(mLoggingEnabled) {
             android.util.Log.w(tag, msg); //make sure to call android.util here because otherwise you will have a recursion
         }
    }
    public static void enableLogging(boolean enabled) {
          mLoggingEnabled = enabled
    }
    //...............
}
```